# Unresolved error in Java Script stored in db.system.js.save on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, stored-procedures

Please I am new to mongoDB and I want to perform a search with js stored in mongoDB. Below is the js code stored in mongoDB.

When I perform the following query:

```
db.eval("dc(cough and asthma and cold)");
```

I get the following error message:

```
{
        "errmsg" : "exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",
        "code" : 16722,
        "ok" : 0
}
```

Please can someone fix the above error for me ? Thanks in advance.

```
// save script to mongoDB
db.system.js.save({
     _id : "countAnd" ,
    value : function(userQuery){


        return userQuery.toLowerCase().split("and").length;
    }
});

//save dc to mongoDB 
db.system.js.save({
    _id : "dc",

    value: function(userQuery){

    var numOfAnds = countAnd(userQuery);


    var uQuery = userQuery.toLowerCase().split("and",numOfAnds);

    var dcResults ="";

        for(var i=0; i<uQuery.length; i++){


                var dcResults =db.records.find({diagnosis:uQuery[i]},{diagnosis:true});



        }

        return dcResults;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take your string in quotes. Like this

```
db.eval("dc('cough and asthma and cold')");
```